# DB2 instance not appearing on system tray

Tags: db2

I have installed DB2 server on windows 2008 R2 server. A default instance 'DB2' was created at the time of installation.

I am building up an environment for Identity manager, and used it's configuration utility to create necessary steps required for connection between the Identity manager and database.

This utility creates another instance and database for the identity manager. However, I do not see this second instance appearing on the system tray icon.

I even performed a windows server restart but still the second instance created is not appearing. Verified from the services window that services for both the instance is started and running.

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance process creation does not include that cosmetic part. This is included as part of the installation process, but not when creating additional instances.

You can add a second systray icon by calling the db2systray.exe as a starting process: msconfig.exe. You have to provide the name of the instance to "monitor":

[image]

For more information, consult the KnowCenter: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0011771.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-5-2-6-117